# Mocha non-global references

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

Let's say I have a structure like so:

```
   /Users/me/Desktop...
    app/
     node_modules/
     subdir/
       test/
         mytest.coffee
```

If I `cd /Users/me/Desktop/app/subdir`, then run mocha tests like this:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script --require ../node_modules/coffee-script ./test --reporter spec --require should -t 5000 --colors -b
```

This works.

But when I change `../node_modules/coffee-script` to `/Users/me/Desktop/app/node_modules/coffee-script`, I receive an error with a duplicate pathname:

```
Cannot find module /Users/me/Desktop/app/Users/me/Desktop/app/node_modules/coffee-script
```

Why is this? The use-case is that I'm trying to not pollute the global namespace from an NPM package, so it uses its install path + node_modules path for deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do `--require coffee-script`? Node will resolve the path to the nearest node_modules folder.

Comment: coffee-script doesn't exist anymore. Now you should use ***--require coffee script***